# Setting up Oracle Database in Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, database, oracle, dependencies

Good day,

I am trying to install Oracle Database in Oracle Linux. However, it is looking for some dependencies. Anybody knows where I can get them?

```
Package: gcc-3.4.6  FAILED  
Package: libaio-0.3.105 FAILED  
Package: glibc-2.3.4-2.41   FAILED  
Package: compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3  FAILED  
Package: compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3  FAILED  
Package: elfutils-libelf-devel-0.97 FAILED  
Package: glibc-devel-2.3.4  FAILED  
Package: glibc-headers-2.3.4    FAILED  
Package: gcc-c++-3.4.6  FAILED  
Package: libaio-devel-0.3.105   FAILED  
Package: libaio-devel-0.3.105   FAILED  
Package: libgcc-3.4.6   FAILED  
Package: libstdc++-3.4.6
```

See screenshot here : http://snag.gy/gwCFB.jpg

Thanks,

Franz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle docs?

https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/entry/oracle_rdbms_server_11gr2_pre

So, something like `yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall`.  Some other discussion notes that they may have changed the package name with Oracle Linux 6.x, with the previous name as `oracle-validated`.  I'm sure that there are other Oracle RDBMS installation notes somewhere on their site.

Comment: That's that worked! :) Although after installing the oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall, I still had some warnings from the oracle db installer about missing dependencies, the packages are already there actually but not the same version (most of them are just slightly different). So I just ignored it and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to try to install them using the package manager of your distribution.

Under Debian-based systems (like Debian and Ubuntu), you can `apt-cache search` and `apt-get install`.

Under redhat-based systems (like Redhat, Fedora, and CentOS), you can use `yum search` and `yum install`.

You have to be careful about packages' versions. If they don't meet the required packages, you have troubles later.

If you failed to find a proper package in your package manager, you can try to search for one on the web. If you could not get one, you will need to install it from source.

Comment: Oracle Linux is RedHat, only with Oracle logo...